# getting NoClassDefFoundError using elastic4s

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, playframework, jackson

I'm using `play 2.6` and `scala 2.12` in my app, and elastic search using elastic4s.

In my `build.sbt`:

```
"com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-core" % "5.6.0",
"com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-http" % "5.6.0",
```

and I keep getting this exception in my log:

```
Exception in thread "I/O dispatcher 16" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.JacksonSupport$
    at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.ResponseHandler$.fromEntity(ResponseHandler.scala:47)
    at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.DefaultResponseHandler.$anonfun$onResponse$1(ResponseHandler.scala:55)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
    at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.DefaultResponseHandler.onResponse(ResponseHandler.scala:55)
    at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.HttpExecutable$RichRestClient$$anon$1.onSuccess(HttpExecutable.scala:27)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$FailureTrackingResponseListener.onSuccess(RestClient.java:597)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:352)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:343)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Trying to figure out what could cause this.

In another log also saw:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Scala module 2.8.8 requires Jackson Databind version >= 2.8.0 and < 2.9.0
```

so it looks like something with the jackson version, or also with the jackson version, but not sure where do I update it or where is it failing exactly...

Someone ever had this issue?
thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Double check if you are importing [`elastic4s-jackson`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Celastic4s-jackson):

```
libraryDependencies += "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-jackson" % "5.6.0"
```

Comment: I used elastic4s and dont remember was never dealing with elastic4s-jackson...? is that possible? my previous app version was using the same thing but this version I upgraded scala to 2.12, can it be that something changed and now I need it?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact same issue with play 2.8 and elastic4s 6.7.3 using the jackson module too
What helped me was running `evicted` and looking at the dependencies each library had and figuring out why it cannot load that particular class . ultimately upgrading to 6.7.8 ended up resolving the issue.
Also if you look in the buid.sbt file for the elasic4s project it lists all the versions it is using https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/build.sbt

Answer (score 0):

You can use jackson-module-scala and exclude the com.fasterxml.jackson which is referenced in elastic4s-http and verify that com.fasterxml.jackson is available in the libraries/classpath when the application is running.